# After deploying a smart contract, if I have 2,000 items, is it possible to mint all of them at the same time?

Tags: solidity, contract-development, blockchain, nft

If I have 2,000 items, is it possible to mint all of them at the same time, or is there a limit for the number of items that I want to mint at the same time?

Comment: Probably the first limitation you'll reach is block gas limit. In mainnet it is 30M as of 2022-08-06.

Answer (score 3):

If we suppose that there is no mint limitation by the item owners (which is commonly implemented in NFT projects), one limitation you may encounter is the number of transaction that can be included in one Ethereum block.

To go deeper, here is an extract of this [article](https://bitsonblocks.net/2016/10/02/gentle-introduction-ethereum/), pretty old though:

*Currently the maximum block size in Ethereum is around 1,500,000 Gas. Basic transactions or payments of ETH from one account to another (ie not a smart contract) have a complexity of 21,000 Gas so you can fit around 70 transactions into a block (1,500,000 / 21,000)*.

Edit: The current block gas limit is 30M, as raised by Ismael.

Comment: The article is from 2016, the current block gas limit is 30M.

Comment: @Ismael Edited my answer, thanks !